# How to put punctuation quotation in Awk command?

Tags: bash, awk

I am new to awk.I just try to write some thing that to exchange my text file.but I  failed.

I want to output like `'hello'`.
I used command `awk '{print "'hello'"}' filename` to do it.but failed:
output like: hello
but I used command `awk '{print "\'hello\'"}' filename` to do it.failed again:
output like:  >
ok.it seems that the awk command do not get what I mean.
So I am confused about that .how to solve the problem.
guys thanks.

Comment: What do you really want to do? The awk script your making is actually just trying to print `'hello'` for every line it finds in your file, but it doesn't modify it.

Comment: Also if you just want to print a message in awk regardless of the file, just do `awk "BEGIN{print \"'hello'\";exit;}"`. You don't need to pass a filename to that.

Comment: I know it.I just try to express the things clearly.

Comment: I try to using awk to automatic generate command sql shell.but in command line.I need the quotation.

Comment: Since you're still starting awk I suggest that you write codes in awk script files first instead so that you won't be confused with quoting in the shell's command-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use double quotes:

```
awk "{print \"'hello'\"}" filename
```

Although that won't really modify your file.

Comment: In this example you need outer double quotes `"` using single fails `'` Like this gives error `awk '{print \"'hello'\"}' filename`

Answer (score 2):

Using the ascii code:

```
awk '{print "\x27" "hello" "\x27"}' filename
```

Using a variable:

```
awk -v q="'" '{print q "hello" q}' filename
```

Example:

```
$ seq 2 > filename
$ awk '{print "\x27" "hello" "\x27"}' filename
'hello'
'hello'
$ awk -v q="'" '{print q "hello" q}' filename
'hello'
'hello'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print "'"'"'hello'"'"'"}' filename
```

Comment: is any other way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

clyfish's answer works, if you *must* have it output single quotes and you *must* use scripts that you pass on the command line.

What I usually do in cases like these, though, when I need to do quoting but I don't want to write a 'real' awk script, is this:

```
awk 'function q(word) { return "\"" word "\"" } 
     { printf("mv %s SomeDir/;", q($0)) }'
```

What I've done is to define a function that returns whatever you pass it in double quotes. Then use printf to actually use it. Without doing that, I would have had to do:

```
awk '{ print("mv \"" $0 "\" SomeDir/;") }';
```

It gets pretty nasty. For more complicated examples, this can be a life saver.

However, suppose you really do need to output something with actual single quotes. In that case dealing with odd shell quoting rules while trying to pass scripts like this on the command line is going to drive you completely insane, so I would suggest you just write a simple throwaway file.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk
# hi.awk
{ print("'hello'") }
```

then call it:

```
awk -f ./hi.awk
```

You don't really even need the `#!` line in the file if you do it that way, but neither does it hurt.